# Is the nRF24L01 IRQ line open-collector?

Tags: interrupts, nrf24l01, open-collector

I need to know whether the nRF24L01(+) has an open-collector IRQ output, or a full push-pull driver. The datasheet doesn't mention this fact.

The reason is that I'm working on a circuit involving two peripherals (an nRF24L01 and another chip) attached to an MCU that has only a single INT pin. If both the devices have open-collector IRQ lines, I can easily just wire them all together with an overall pullup resistor, and all will work fine. If however, the nRF24L01 has a full push/pull driver on the IRQ line, then this is impossible, and instead I'll have to buffer it somehow (perhaps with a 7407 or similar). When the interrupt fires, I can query each device over SPI to enquire which device fired the interrupt.

Comment: The datasheet lists it as a "digital output" and all the timing diagrams imply that it's pulled high or pushed low as appropriate. I would assume it's *not* open collector but maybe a question for the guys at Nordic rather than here.

Comment: I have never had to add any form of pullup to the IRQ line. It's a normal push-pull output.

Comment: @Majenko - if that's intended as an answer, could you make it a real answer? Then I can upvote/star it.

Comment: @LeoNerd I was just gathering more detail for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRQ pin is a normal Push-Pull output.

There is a very good tutorial document available on the internet: [nrf24l01_tutorial_0.pdf](http://www.diyembedded.com/tutorials/nrf24l01_0/nrf24l01_tutorial_0.pdf)

In there it says this about the IRQ line:

> The remaining two pins are CE and IRQ. CE is used to control data transmission
>   and reception when in TX and RX modes, respectively. IRQ is the interrupt pin, and is
>   active-low. There are three internal interrupts that can cause this pin to go low when they
>   are active. Each of these bits can be masked out such that when the bit’s respective
>   interrupt becomes active, the status of the IRQ pin is not changed.

It goes on to say:

> The SPI pins are all done, so now let’s get to the seventh pin from the top, the
>   IRQ pin. This guy is basically the interrupt pin to signal your microcontroller that
>   something interesting has happened. You can set interrupts for any combination of the
>   following events: data received, data transmitted, and maximum number of transmit
>   retries reached (this particular one is related to the 24L01’s hardware link-layer, more on
>   that later). If you’re not using interrupts, this pin isn’t required because you can poll the
>   24L01’s STATUS register over SPI to see if any interrupt has occurred, but it’s still faster
>   (in general) to check the status of an IO pin than to send an SPI command and then wait
>   for the response. NOTE: the IRQ pin is ACTIVE-LOW. It is normally high, but when
>   an interrupt is asserted, the pin will go low.

Although it doesn't explicitly say it, the wording implies that it is a normal push-pull output, otherwise one would expect the author to make mention of it being open collector and a pull-up resistor being required.

Also, in [the datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf) the pin is labelled as a "Digital Output".  In the DC characteristics in section 5.6 it lists the output voltages for a "Digital output pin" (table 13).  An open collector wouldn't have an output voltage, so it must be push-pull.

Comment: Ahyes; that is a most helpful reading-between-the-lines there. Looks like I'll have to put an additional buffer on it somehow. Either a 1-gate 7407, or perhaps a PNP-transistor out of the nRF and run the INT line on the MCU "backwards"; active-high.

Comment: You're looking to have multiple IRQ signals going into a single INT pin?

Comment: Yes; if either the nRF or the sensor want to raise an interrupt, they can do so. Since they both have status registers available on SPI I can easily query them both to see which one raised it. It's a standard technique - PCs call it "IRQ sharing"

Comment: Yes, it's very common - especially on MCUs where you tend to have limited resources.  You may be able to get away with 2 diodes and a resistor.  Google "diode AND gate".  Of course, if the sensor is already OC, then just a single diode and resistor would probably work.

Comment: Yeah - a diode looks like my best bet here. I don't even need the resistor - I can get the ATtiny to do internal pullup. And the sensor chip already does open-drain INT anyway, so all I need to do is add a single diode to the circuit. This seems best.

Answer (score 2):

> If however, the nRF24L01 has a full push/pull driver on the IRQ line,
>   then this is impossible, and instead I'll have to buffer it somehow
>   (perhaps with a 7407 or similar).

If it's push/pull then diode OR the two outputs with a single pull-up resistor - this would save a buffer chip.

Comment: I hadn't thought of a diode. I was considering a 1-gate 7407 (e.g. SN74AHC1G07, a tiny little SOT-23-5 package), but a simple diode would of course do it too. Sometimes I forget the simple things ;)